# Android EditText как минимум одна большая буква

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения, android-edittext

EditText использую как пароль, он должен содержать как минимум одну большую букву, такой код не помог

```
btRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etLogin.getText().toString().equals(0)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (etPassword.getText().length() <= 5) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password is too short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (!etPassword.getText().toString().matches("[A-Za-z]*")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password must have at least one big letter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }



    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте `matcher.find()`:

```
    String upperChar = "([A-Z])";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(upperChar);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(etPassword.getText().toString());
    ...
    ...
    else if (!matcher.find()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password must have at least one big letter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Вроде работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вообще вместо двух проверок пароля на длину и потом regexp, можно юзать одну - с помощью regexp. В этом же regexp можно задать проверку на один символ верхнего регистра. Попробуйте такую регулярку

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$
```

в ней идет проверка на строчные и прописные латинские буквы, цифры